# How can I have Emacs window(s) and cygwin shell running simultaneously on Windows?

Tags: linux, shell, emacs, cygwin

I have Cygwin working with Emacs 24.3.1 on windows 8.1 with Emacs downloaded from the Cygwin installation, however I can't use Emacs and the Cygwin shell at the same time or open up multiple Emacs windows. I want to be able to compile and run, use make etc using the shell but it appears I can only use either shell or the text editor. I want Emacs to open up just like in Linux using the command shell like this:

```
emacs file.c &
```

and be able to interact with both the shell and the file. How do I do this?

Comment: Use a terminal multiplexer like `screen`, which is included in cygwin.

Comment: Why not open a shell window in Emacs. That's what I always do when working in a terminal environment. You can also open as many shells as you like by renaming the buffers.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of the situation is that the Emacs that comes with Cygwin's `emacs` package runs inside the terminal, and to have Emacs be separate from the terminal, or to have multiple Emacs frames, you need to install the `emacs-w32` package.  After you do that, everything should just work.  You'll also get image and PDF support for Emacs.

There's also the `emacs-X11` package, which uses the X window manager.  I have no experience with it or with X, so I can't say more than that it exists.

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend **tmux**, which is (sort of) the successor to screen and is also available in Cygwin

```
$ tmux -V
tmux 1.9a
```